# how javascript alert function work in String var Of java on web browser

Tags: javascript, validation, jsf, alert

i have a String var in class
String message;

```
private int checkConstraints() 
    int a = 0;
    if (docProcessId==0) {
        a++;
   message = "<script language=\"javascript\"> alert('Please Select Doc Process Name'); </script>";
    }else if (refTypeName.equals("")) {
        a++;
        message = "<script> alert('Enter Reference Type Name!');</script>";
    }

    return a;

}
```

actually i am doing like this but when this method is called not equals to 0 then message equals to whole the string print on page not giving alert any solution please

Comment: in web page where you append this string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF by default HTML-escapes all model values as part of [XSS attack prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf/7725675#7725675). Your concrete problem suggests that you had no idea of that. You can "solve" it by using `<h:outputText>` with `escape` attribute set to `false`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.message}" escape="false" />
```

---

However, your concrete problem is bigger. You're in JSF/MVC perspective basically making two major design mistakes here:

1. Writing HTML code in model instead of in the view.
2. Performing validation in an action method instead of in a validator.

You should be writing HTML code in the view, not in the model. You should be performing validation using a normal JSF validator. JSF has a lot of builtin validators.

Besides, not really a design mistake, but more an user experience mistake, there's a third mistake: using JavaScript alerts to show validation messages. This is simply too 1990 and Web 1.0. We're currently in 2013 and have learnt a lot, a lot of the user experience failures made back then. Using JavaScript alerts to show validation messages is one of them.

Here's the right approach using JSF-provided validation facilities:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.docProcessId}" required="true" 
        requiredMessage="Please Select Doc Process Name">
        <f:selectItems ... />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.refTypeName}" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Enter Reference Type Name" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

That's it. The `required="true"` tells JSF that those inputs are required. The `requiredMessage` attribute allows you to specify custom messages for required validation. The messages will be displayed in place as declared by `<h:messages>`. You can customize the layout by `layout` attribute and by CSS means like `infoClass`, `errorClass`, etc. You can even manually loop over it and manually create annoying alerts for each message instead of using `<h:messages>`:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{facesContext.messageList}" var="message">
    <script>alert("#{message.summary}");</script>
</ui:repeat>
```