# JSF 2.1 and Seam: s:token still required

Tags: jsf-2, seam

I'm upgrading a webapp from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1 (using Apache MyFaces implementation).
The app is also using Seam and to prevent XSRF attacks, I was using the `<s:token>` tag.

Now I wonder if the `<s:token>` is still necessary with JSF 2.1.

Anyone can provide me with some information on this?

Cheers
Frank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSF 1.x was CSRF sensitive because the value of the hidden input field `javax.faces.ViewState` was easily predictable. It was composed of some fixed prefix value with an incremental numeric suffix. So, when the JSF 1.x webapp has a XSS hole (which is fairly easy to accidently overlook in legacy JSP), one could easily prepare a CSRF attack by predicting the next `javax.faces.ViewState` value based on the current value (and relying on JSF 1.0/1.1 feature of blindly creating a new view instead of throwing `ViewExpiredException`).

Since JSF 2.x, both XSS and CSRF attacks are much harder to be accomplished. Note that without a XSS hole, it's practically impossible to prepare a successful CSRF attack. JSP's successor Facelets has implicit XSS attack prevention. The only way to have a XSS hole in JSF 2.x is explicitly using `<h:outputText escape="false">` on user-controlled input. Even then if there's one, the hidden input field `javax.faces.ViewState` is now a long and auto-generated value. It's not possible to predict the next value for this.

So, the `<s:token>` has not really a value anymore in JSF 2.x.

#### See also:

- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf/7725675#7725675)