# what are the security requirements to a jsf page?

Tags: java, security, jsf, jsf-2, report

I created a application using JSF which is intergrated with glassfish for database files etc, but i have been asked to write a report about security requirements for a jsf application.
I have been told to write an introduction
then Security Mechanisms Proposed, then Implementation of the Mechanisms into the JSF Pages and Implementation of the Mechanisms into the
Business Logic.

**This is the question**
"This report must include an introduction about the security requirements and the sensitive
resources that need to be protected. Then, you should explain how these requirements have
been addressed by your solution making an explicit reference to mechanisms used and how the
mechanisms would be implemented into the different pats of the application (i.e., the web
pages, the beans and the server). You should use diagrams/screenshots to communicate your
ideas. "

My question is does anyone know what i can write for the introduction, Im confused.

Comment: This is a quite broad question and sounds too much like a homework question. Try reading into the concepts and breaking down it in multiple more specific questions. I think this is a good starting point as to the JSF part (which is the frontend, not the backend/business logic! that part is usually done by EJB): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf If you're still unsure, just ask the tutor/professor/whoever gave you this assignment how to start.

Comment: And the title is totally off... The **only one** that can tell what the security requirements are of **your** pages is **you**