# Is Primefaces have in-build support to prevent the attacks

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to this field.

I do not know whether the `Primefaces` have the in-build support to prevent the below listed attacks or not.

1. `Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)`.
2. `Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)`.
3. `Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards`.
4. `Broken Authentication`.

If not, Then what to do to prevent the attacks.

Comment: JSF already support http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf

Comment: PrimeFaces is not a MVC framework. It's just an UI component library (which is to be used on top of JSF, which in turn is a MVC framework).

Comment: Yeah, yes....Thank you lot.