# Can use special characters and html tag in p:outputLabel without escape false?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Can use special characters and html tag in **p:outputLabel** without escape false?When escape false is ok.escape= "false" can be xss hole .Is there other way?

Comment: you should add more background to your question

Comment: If a  `p:outputLabel` with `escape="false"` works and does what it is intended to do and is used in a way that it is intended to be used, _Why do you need it to work **without** escape="false" then?_

Comment: escape="false" can be xss hole.

Comment: xss and jsf are completely separate technologies/methods.

Comment: see at there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf