# Why p_auth validation is not working in Liferay 6?

Tags: security, jsf-2, liferay, csrf, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2-ce-ga3, primefaces 6 and JSF2.1. I have enabled CSRF protection for my portlet adding the follow code in liferay portal-ext.properties and portlet portal-ext.properties:

```
auth.token.check.enabled=true
auth.token.impl=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SessionAuthToken
```

futhermore, I've added in portlet.xml

```
<init-param>
  <name>check-auth-token</name>
  <value>true</value>
</init-param>
```

For test, I removed `p_auth=<code>` from my `form` url then I submitted the form and it's worked. That's not good, I't should not allow the request without the token.

1. did I forget add a filter in configuration?
2. how liferay check the p_auth?
3. should I check manually p_auth token in my bean like this [tutorial](https://muralie39.wordpress.com/2014/06/22/authentication-token-in-liferay/)?

Comment: Please also check existence of `auth.token.ignore.actions`

Comment: @AndreAlbert I haven't created that properties manully, does is created automatically?

Comment: @cheloncio, is your request and Ajax request?

Comment: @stiemannkj1 java request

Comment: @cheloncio, that doesn't answer my question. Can you add the view xhtml code and steps to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay's `p_auth` token protects against CSRF during the ACTION_PHASE of the portlet lifecycle. I believe that it is enabled by default in Liferay 6.2, so you shouldn't need to configure anything for it.

The `p_auth` token must be present for a form to submit without error during the ACTION_PHASE. However, [the `p_auth` parameter has no effect during the RESOURCE_PHASE](https://community.liferay.com/de/forums/-/message_boards/message/38790296) which is the phase where JSF Ajax form submissions are executed. So you may be dealing with a JSF Ajax request. Thankfully, [JSF also has its own CSRF protection enabled by default in the view state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf). So you are safe from CSRF with both Ajax and non-Ajax form submissions when you use Liferay Faces.

If you confirm that `p_auth` has no effect during a non-Ajax form submission, there may be a security vulnerability (or an issue with your configuration). You should update to the latest version of Liferay Portal* and retest. If you are still having issues, report a **secure** issue: https://issues.liferay.com/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?pid=10952&issuetype=1.

*[Liferay Portal 6.2 GA6](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.2.5%20GA6/) is the latest in the 6.2 line, and [Liferay Portal 7.0 GA7](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/7.0.6%20GA7/) is the latest CE release overall. Of course there are EE releases that may have more bug fixes as well.

Comment: Thanks you very much