# JSF: <h:outputText without using the current template / css -> output is email content

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have a issue to display my email body correctly.

I have the following `h:outputText`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{mybean.selectedEmail.body}" escape="false" />
```

It´s working fine and the content is showing, but the issue is in my page I´m using also the CSS style classes from the current template page.
How can I do this, that I will use for the `h:outputText` only the HTML / Css from the email (body) ?

Any suggestion / code examples?

Comment: Try using an `iframe`

Comment: Great, it´s working with iframe srcdoc="..."

Comment: also using an outputText to display user controlled data opens a security leak for [XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf).