# Java allow exceptions to XSS filters

Tags: java, jstl, xss

*I red [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159729/java-best-practices-to-prevent-cross-site-scripting) and others about using JSTL in this matter.*

My issue is a bit different. One of our features allows users to write hash-tags in their comments.

Whenever the comments are listed, a server script turns all `#fooHastag` becomes `<a href='tag?fooHashtag'>#fooHashtag</a>`.

Then all the comments are listen on the GUI using JSTL:

```
<c:forEach items="${comments}" var = "comment">
    ${fn:escapeXml(comment)}
</c:forEach
```

As expected this piece of code also escapes the hash links built on the server. If I remove the `fn:escapeXml` than the application won't be safe anymore.

Do you have any idea about a fix for this? (other than manually building a xss filter) It would be great if somehow I would be able to use JSTL's `escapeXml` on the server before converting the hashtags. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of ways to solve it:

- escape before adding the tags. Use a decent html encoder instead of escapeXml (HTML isn't even XML)
- add tags, then run through owasp antisamy. No escaping
- Move the tag to link functionality into javascript.