# How to sanitize HTML code to prevent XSS attacks in Java or JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, xss

I'm writing a servlet-based application in which I need to provide a messaging system. I'm in a rush, so I choose [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) to provide editing capabilities, and I currently insert the generated html directly in the web page displaying all messages (messages are stored in a MySQL databse, fyi). CKEditor already filters HTML based on a white list, but a user can still inject malicious code with a POST request, so this is not enough.

A good library already exists to prevent XSS attacks by filtering HTML tags, but it's written in PHP: [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

So, **is there a similar mature library that can be used in Java** ?
A simple string replacement based on a white list doesn't seem to be enough, since **I'd like to filter malformed tags too** (which could alter the design of the page on which the message is displayed).

If there isn't, then how should I proceed? An XML parser seems overkill.

*Note: There are a lot of questions about this on SO, but all the answers refer to filter ALL HTML tags: I want to keep valid formatting tags.*

Comment: Alternative: Use BBCode for user input, there are nice editors for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [AntiSamy](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project). ([That's what I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723/best-regex-to-catch-xss-cross-site-scripting-attack-in-java))

Answer (score 22):

I'd recommend using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this. Here's an extract of relevance from [its site](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

> ### [Sanitize untrusted HTML](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)
>
> #### Problem
>
> You want to allow untrusted users to supply HTML for output on your website (e.g. as comment submission). You need to clean this HTML to avoid [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) attacks.
>
> #### Solution
>
> Use the jsoup HTML [`Cleaner`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html) with a configuration specified by a [`Whitelist`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html).
>
> ```
> String unsafe = 
>       "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
> String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
>       // now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
> ```

Jsoup offers more advantages than that as well. See also [Pros and Cons of HTML parsers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers).

Answer (score 2):

If none of the ready-made options seem like enough, there is an excellent series of articles on XSS and attack prevention at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleIntroductionToXSS). It should provide plenty of information to work with, if you end up going down that path.