# how to prevent javascript injection in java

Tags: javascript, java, javascript-injection

I have a rich text area where the user can type something. I am trying to prevent JavaScript injection using the following regex:

```
return input == null ? null : input.replaceAll("(?i)<script.*?>.*?</script.*?>", "") // case 1
            .replaceAll("(?i)<.*?javascript:.*?>.*?</.*?>", "") // case 2
            .replaceAll("(?i)<.*?\\s+on.*?>.*?</.*?>", ""); // case 3
```

Above, `input` is the text from the rich text area and I am using this regex to avoid possible JavaScript injections.

The problem is case 3. If the user's text contains `"on"`, all the text before `"on"` gets removed.

How can I make the last case more rigid and avoid the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove "on" and everything up to the end of the tag, you can use this:
.replaceAll("(?i)(<.*?\s+)on.*?(>.*?)", "$1$2");

This renders "ACD" as "ACD". But be aware that if someone puts a ">" character inside the script, it will mess up the regex...

**EDIT**: the moral of my remark is that I would not recommend a custom parsing to remove javascript code. I suggest you get yourself acquainted with the answer to the following question: [Java: Best way to remove Javascript from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156723/java-best-way-to-remove-javascript-from-html) and probably use Jsoup.clean (if it is possible in your environment).

Comment: JSoup removes the attributes from HTML. Does it also work with just plain text. Example: it doenst work on "I like this site because <script>alert('Injected!');</script> teaches me a lot"

Comment: It does accept just text... But it might do some stuff that you don't want: it removed <body> tag completely (it should not be within the text) and it added a newline when I tried it with <p>. Did you think about escaping the html (including javascript) instead of removing it?