# Is there an API / LIB to remove JavaScript in the JavaBackend?

Tags: java, javascript, xss, code-injection

We integrated a wysiwyg editor in our website. Now we got the problem that some stuff gets saved in the Database what we might don't want, like JavaScript and so on.

Is there and API / LIB who could filter this stuff out for us? We prefer it to do in our Java Backend. Maybe something that's bases on black and white lists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "Purify" HTML code to prevent XSS attacks in Java or JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587199/how-to-purify-html-code-to-prevent-xss-attacks-in-java-or-jsp)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option could be: 
[OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/)

Answer (score 2):

Try jsoup :

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer