# insertion of tags into a textarea

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

how can I insert some tags into textarea please (formating text  **...** ) ?

I've tried this code but it doesn't make a real change to the html code :

```
<textarea id="textareabuttons${boucle.index}" name="text"
                                rows="6" cols="165" disabled><c:set var="string1"
                                    value="${post.text}" /><c:set var="string2"
                                    value="${fn:replace(string1, 
                                '<gras>', '<strong>')}" /><c:set
                                    var="string3"
                                    value="${fn:replace(string2, 
                                '</gras>', '</strong>')}" /><c:set
                                    var="string4"
                                    value="${fn:replace(string3, 
                                '<italique>', '<em>')}" /><c:set
                                    var="string5"
                                    value="${fn:replace(string4, 
                                '</italique>', '</em>')}" />${string5}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `<textarea>` element by default preformats any content. So, you'll only see literal content instead of parsed content. You can not turn it on or off by any attribute, let alone CSS. If you want to present/preview parsed content, then you should put it in another HTML element such as `<div>`. You can if necessary throw in some CSS to make it to look like a disabled textarea (background color, inset border, etc).

Beware of [XSS attack holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java/2658941#2658941) though when redisplaying user-controlled input this way. Consider [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to sanitize content by a whitelist. See also [How to sanitize HTML code to prevent XSS attacks in Java or JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587199/how-to-purify-html-code-to-prevent-xss-attacks-in-java-or-jsp/3587257#3587257)

Comment: but using <div> tag will allow the author of the message to add some html tag, no ?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean with my last paragraph. Your initial approach also did it, by the way, given that you're attempting to get your own `<em>`, etc to work. Even if that had actually worked in `<textarea>`, you'd still have faced the very same XSS attack problem.

Comment: The problem that I can't change that textarea to a <div> tag because I have prepeared a link which allows the answerer to answer a post, making that disabled textarea an enabled one :/

Comment: Just switch between `<textarea>` and `<div>` instead of `<textarea>` and `<textarea disabled>`? I'm not sure about the hard part in that.

Comment: Thank you I'll think about, but BalusC could you suggest me a good topic on which I can practice more Java EE language please ? And what is the most striking difference between .net, java ee, php webapps please ?