# Anti-XSS java libraries

Tags: java, xss

I'm looking for a java library that can provide protection against [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). I'm writing a server, and would like to validate my user's input doesn't contain malicious javascript.

Which library would you recommend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "Purify" HTML code to prevent XSS attacks in Java or JSP ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587199/how-to-purify-html-code-to-prevent-xss-attacks-in-java-or-jsp) and [Best regex to catch XSS (Cross-site Scripting) attack (in Java)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723/best-regex-to-catch-xss-cross-site-scripting-attack-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [AntiSamy](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project). ([That's what I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723/best-regex-to-catch-xss-cross-site-scripting-attack-in-java))

Comment: I think AntiSamy does not provide the functionality of detection if an XSS is performed. Can you suggest a library which would help the detection of the same?

Comment: XSS can't truly be detected until its successfully executed in a browser context.  However, antisamy does generate an error list so you can see reasons why a particular DOM was rejected.  At this stage however, antisamy hasn't been touched since 2013, so it should probably not be used anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) HTML sanitization project with much success.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project

Policies can be defined (or predefined policies can be used) that enable you to control what types of HTML elements are allowed on the String being validated/sanitized. A listener can be used as the HTML is sanitized in order to determine what elements are getting rejected, giving you flexibility around how to communicate this back to the client. Other than an easy implementation, I also like this library because it is produced and maintained by OWASP, a long standing organization whose aim is web security.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept HTML from the users, then AntiSamy or something like jsoup makes sense. However, if you just want a good set of escapers, you can use a library such as [CSL](https://github.com/coverity/coverity-security-library)

We have a cheat sheet online that shows how to use it in many HTML contexts ([aka HTML constructs](http://security.coverity.com/document/2013/Mar/fixing-xss-a-practical-guide-for-developers.html)):

Comment: Don't use Jsoup for security validation purposes.  Jsoup's design is to "fix" invalid HTML, and many XSS attacks are deliberately invalid... so Jsoup "fixes" it and your validation likely flags it as good.

Answer (score 0):

The great post how to prevent XSS attacks in different situations is posted in the following stack: [Avoid XSS and allow some html tags with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824338/avoid-xss-and-allow-some-html-tags-with-javascript/19943011#19943011)

Comment: I would stay away from using javascript to do this--most attacks these days are DOM-based, and javascript has a technique called monkeypatching that can allow an attacker to take control of any client-side function.

Comment: @avgvstvs if the attacker already gained access to the ability to do monkey patching, then he can basically already just do anything he would be able to do through XSS.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels my point is that as a web developer, the front end simply is the *wrong* place to implement *any* kind of XSS prevention, because the server has zero control over what goes on in the browser.  The browser is untrusted, all the time.

Comment: @avgvstvs It depends on the application. If App doesn't render your users content and hence execute it how the attacker exploit this vulnerability ?

Comment: @user1459144, the only way to guarantee that an app doesn't render user content, is to 1.)  Never display user input in a browser, 2.)  Always escape user data sent back for the appropriate context.  The first applies to so few apps it can pretty much be tossed.  The second, dictates that the escaping be done on the backend, before the page payload reaches the user.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on how to sanitize your inputs using OWASP library, may be can be helpful https://leantechblog.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/preventing-xss-sanitize-app-inputs/