# REGEXP not allowing single character at the starting

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regexp for XSS attack validation. Its checking `<..> </>` datas correctly. But when I type single character at first its not allowing any single character (eg: if I type 'a' its not allowing). Can anyone help me on this?

```
/^(|\/|[^\/>][^>]+|\/[^>][^>]+)$/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best regex to catch XSS (Cross-site Scripting) attack (in Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723/best-regex-to-catch-xss-cross-site-scripting-attack-in-java)

Comment: What are the expectations? What do you want to do?

Comment: @revo it should not allow xss attack

Comment: @Amy - javascript validation I want

Comment: Short answer: not possible unless you make a whitelist not a blacklist.

Comment: @VinothBabu Please read the first sentence of the first answer:  "Don't do this with regular expressions."

Comment: @Amy I disagree, the question you linked to is not about JavaScript, it is about Java

Comment: @PeterOlson If the answer in Java is "don't do this", the answer in JavaScript is also "don't do this"

Comment: @Amy "Don't do this" is only half of the answer, the other half is "here's what you should do instead", which will be different across programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that Regex is not optimal for XSS attack validation as comments said :

This regex need at least two characters because of the two `+`, which means between one and unlimited characters. `*` can be used to specify between zero and unlimited characters.